# Same animation for all beamer slides

Tags: beamer, animations

I need to put same animation for all slides. I mean all paragraphs, bullets, images. After opening slide automatically work all animations of opened  slide (all items of this slide). This is same for all slides. What is a simple solution for that?

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
first paragraph
\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}
\hspace{4cm}
\vspace{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,natwidth=69,natheight=87]{yourimage} \end{figure} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you're asking here is unclear. Why not post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to explain what you mean?

Comment: I need to add one animation for all items in this slide

Comment: In MS powerpoint we select all items and add animation.So,all item animation happen same time,I need to do that..I think u can understand my need..

Comment: Using  \begin{itemize}[<+->]  display bullets one by one..But i need to display all bullets same time within one animation

Comment: Edit your question to clarify it and add your code. Please do not post it as a comment.

Comment: If you want to show all bullets at once, what else do you want to animate, after all?